# formatting of updated mysqli data on a table

Tags: php, html

I've a simple issue which I'm trying to solve. I am updating a table several times and each time I updat it, I want to show it in the table in formatted way like I'm updating a table name remarks.  When I first update it, it shows in my view table like

```
hello i m usman
```

the next time i updated it it shows like

```
hello i m usman  usman is a  good boy
```

the issue is i wanted to show it in this way

```
i  m usman
usman is a good boy
```

means change the formatting of an update data each time its updated in a new line instead show it in on line like its update on sql

Comment: not sure if I get what you wanted here, can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
update table <table_name> set <column_name> = concat(<column_name>,'\r\n','<new value>') where <column_id> = <column_id_value>
```